# Search inside LDAP Server

Tags: ldap, openldap

I was wondering if someone know, when i search an entity over the Ldap server, would i get also it's sub folders and the data inside.
for example i have the following:

```
*dn:EPC-SubscriberGroupId=AllInOne,
 EPC-SubscriberGroupsName=EPC-SubscriberGroups,
 applicationName=EPC-EpcNode, nodeName=jambala
changetype:add
objectClass: EPC-SubscriberGroup
EPC-SubscriberGroupDescription:Voice and Data flat rate
EPC-SubscribedServices:PeerToPeer
EPC-SubscribedServices:Skype
EPC-SubscribedServices:Chat

dn:EPC-Name=EPC-SubscriberQualification,
 EPC-SubscriberGroupId=AllInOne,
 EPC-SubscriberGroupsName=EPC-SubscriberGroups,
 applicationName=EPC-EpcNode,nodeName=jambala
changetype:add
objectClass: EPC-SubscriberQualification
EPC-SubscriberQualificationData:QosProfileId:10000*
```

so if i will set a query that will try to fetch the entity Epc-SubscriberGroup of SubscriberGroupAllInOne, i will also retrieve the sub folder ( object ) EPC-SubscriberQualification

Hope it's clear enough,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When searching LDAP, you generally set 3 things. The start point in the hierarchy, the search itself and what you want returned.

You will need to demonstrate what you've already tried to get more help. in general terms, it is certainly possible to get many entries back from a single search.